How to start up Jupyter without Token
So I recently just encountered an issue with my jupyter notebook. Its asking for tokens. Even after I use the "jupyter server list" command to get the token, still not working. Any help please
"jupyter server list" command to get the token, still not working. Any help please

jupyter lab --port-retries=0 --ip 0.0.0.0 --allow-root --IdentityProvider.token="" --ServerApp.password=""

Or:
jupyter lab --port-retries=0 --ip 0.0.0.0 --allow-root --config=jupyter_notebook_config.py --debug

In your jupyter_notebook_config.py add:
c.ServerApp.token = ""
c.ServerApp.password = ""

